# What if doublehashing function returns 0?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

in the context of handling collisions in hashmaps

What happens is the second hash function returns 0?
We are supposed to increment the result of the first hash function by the result of the second one, but what happens if the second one is zero?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For double hashing, you can use h2(x)+1 as the second function to guarantee it never returns `0`, at the same time h2(x)+1 is universal hash function if h2(x) is.